# Trying to send email to list of users

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I'm trying to set up a thing to send an email to users who have their Subscribed set to true. I think I'm getting the users, but the email address is something I'm working on.

I tried this to get the addresses, but it's not working:

```
var subbed = db.Users.Where(u => u.Subscribed == true);

var emailFrom = WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["emailfrom"];

var emailTo = subbed.Select(s => s.Email).ToString();

MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage(emailFrom, emailTo)
{
    Subject = "This Is The Subject",
    IsBodyHtml = true,
    Body = "This is the body"
};
```

The emailTo variable seems to be the problem from what I can tell in the debugger.

Comment: What is not working? What is the problem? 
`it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed what was expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`emailTo` is currently calling the `ToString` method of your collection, which is probably not what you want. If you want a delimited list of email addresses, you might do something like this:

```cs
var emailTo = string.Join(";", subbed.Select(s => s.Email))
// example output: "bob@example.com;jane@example.com"
```

Comment: thanks, I had a little trouble with that but changing the semi to a comma did the trick.